# How to Keep selected value select after page reload in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I dont know exactly how to do this. I have try tu put in Session using Session::put() and get the curent session with session::get() but still nothing work..

my blade.php

```
  <select name="tahun" class="form-control">
        <option>-- Semua --</option>
      @for($tahun_skr = $tahun_skr_bgt; $tahun_skr >= $tahun_awal_bgt; $tahun_skr--)
        <option value="{{ $tahun_skr }}" selected="{{ $tahun_skr }}">{{ $tahun_skr }}</option>
      @endfor
      </select>
```

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $tahun_awal_bgt = 1990;
        $tahun_skr_bgt = date('Y');
return view('laporan.posisikeuangan_laporan')->with(['tahun_awal_bgt' => $tahun_awal_bgt,'tahun_skr_bgt' => $tahun_skr_bgt]); }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: This code: `<option value="{{ $tahun_skr }}" selected="{{ $tahun_skr }}">` is putting the selected attribute in every single option, that will not work as you hope.  Only add the `selected` attribute for teh single one you want to appear selected.  Further, how is any one of them supposed to be selected if `$tahun_skr` gets decremented with each loop? What variable IS the "selected" value?

Comment: @cale_b the `selected` value always 1990. hei @cale_b can u give me example keep selected value with laravel ? Not necessarily like what I asked just give an example with laravel. that will be great thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer based on your comment , you need to add `selected` attribute only when the value is `1990` which is `$tahun_awal_bgt` variable

```
 <option value="{{ $tahun_skr }}" {{ $tahun_skr == $tahun_awal_bgt ? "selected" : "" }} >{{ $tahun_skr }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects

> Route::post('user/profile', function () {
>      // Validate the request...
>
> return back()->withInput();
>   });